# What performance can I expect from using an RTX 4090 with an old Intel NUC for ML?

Tags: gpu

I have a 5 year old intel NUC that I would like to use a machine learning server. I thought of connecting an RTX 4090 to it using a Razer Core X through its USB-C port. But can I expect to make full use of the GPU using the comparably much weaker NUC?
Would creating a full PC with the GPU yield better results? Does anybody have experience in this area?

Comment: Impossible to say. It depends entirely on how CPU bound your task is. If 99.9% of the task happens on the GPU then you might be fine, if not then *shrug*.

Comment: mostly going to run keras models

Comment: If your choice is eGPU or entire new PC, why not just get the eGPU and see if your results are satisfying ? If not, you can still use the GPU in a new build. Mind you, apart from the possible CPU bound scenarios, your USB-C is likely 3.1 Gen 2 at best with 10Gbps throughput speeds. If your NUC has thunderbolt, you can get upto 40Gbps using that instead. Again depending on workloud, this might make the difference you are looking for.

Comment: The problem is eGPUs are insanely expensive

Comment: So my NUC supports 40GB thunderbolt. So everything should work out, right?

Comment: While this is alot better then USB-C especially for throughput heavy workloads, it wont make a big difference for CPU bound workloads ofcourse. As for the price, an enclosure will set you back from 400-600€. Not a fun loss to take, but compared to the GPU price and possible future use cases (laptop + eGPU for on the go compute), it might be worth trying before upgrading your entire PC. A definitive answer on your question cannot be given without knowing the workload.